# Samba Domain is same as hostname, fastest way to change?

Tags: 14.04, server, samba, domain-server, samba4

So, I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf7Hk8qWt1Q&index=5&list=WL) tutorial for my first ever samba Domain Controller setup.

However, I wasn't really thinking straight during the process, and assigned the domain name the same as the hostname.

domain: example.local

Hostname: example.example.local

This results in errors when I type the following:

```
root@example:/home/user/samba4# /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain provision --realm=example.local --domain=EXAMPLE --adminpass="4A-><>ion" --server-role=dc --dns-backend=SAMBA_INTERNAL
```

I receive the following in return:

```
ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): Provision failed - ProvisioningError: guess_names: Domain 'EXAMPLE' must not be equal to short host name 'EXAMPLE'!
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 442, in run
    nosync=ldap_backend_nosync, ldap_dryrun_mode=ldap_dryrun_mode)
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2025, in provision
    sitename=sitename, rootdn=rootdn, domain_names_forced=(samdb_fill == FILL_DRS))
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 627, in guess_names
    raise ProvisioningError("guess_names: Domain '%s' must not be equal to short host name '%s'!" % (domain, netbiosname))
```

I'm not looking for answers and comments that focus on my lack of experience or noobness.

I'm simply looking for an answer to this error, even if it's not due to the names being identical.

I'm looking for the fastest way to change the hostname or the domain name so that they are different and usable, even if the fastest way is to install samba all over again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you might have to remove all of the apps you just installed. Use purge, but purge will not remove the samba4 folder in your home directory, so you will have to do that as root. 
Now, install everything again, however give a different netbios domain.

It should work fine after that.